# SQL - Select with specific conditions in sub-query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use a query to select all the data of a company that answers a specific condition but I have trouble doing so. The following is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT *
  FROM company a
 WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.company_id 
                  FROM provider b 
                 WHERE b.service_id IN (2, 4));
```

What I intend for the role of the sub-query (using the table below) to be, is to select the `company_id` that possess the `service_id` `2` **and** `4`.

So in this example, it would only return the `company_id` `5`:

```
+----------------+
| provider TABLE |
+----------------+

+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       id       |   company_id   |   service_id   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|        1       |        3       |        2       |
|        2       |        5       |        2       |
|        3       |        5       |        4       |
|        4       |        9       |        6       |
|        5       |        9       |        7       |
|       ...      |       ...      |       ...      |
```

As you may have guessed, the use of the `IN` in the sub-query does not fulfill my needs, it will select the `company_id` `5` but also the `company_id` `3`.
I understand why, `IN` exists to check if a value matches any value in a list of values so it is not really what I need.

So my question is:

> How can I replace the `IN` in my sub-query to select `company_id`
>   having the `service_id` `2` and `4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subquery should be:

```
 SELECT b.company_id 
 FROM provider b 
 WHERE b.service_id IN (2, 4)
 GROUP BY  b.company_id 
 HAVING COUNT(b.service) = 2
```

Comment: this only works if there are no duplicates `company_id/service_id` couples

Comment: @GMB you are right. I assume you wont put same service twice. Doesnt make sense an attribute be repeated like `color = (white, white)`

Comment: Thank you Juan, that answer is what needed also thanks GMB for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can self-`JOIN` the provider table to find companies that own both needed services.

```
SELECT p1.company_id
FROM provider p1
INNER JOIN provider p2 on p2.company_id = p1.company_id and p2.service_id = 2
WHERE p1.service_id = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other answers are correct if you want to see all company detail instead of only Company_id you can use two `EXISTS()` for each service_id.

```
SELECT *
FROM Company C 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM Provider P1 
              WHERE C.company_id = P1.company_id 
              AND P1.service_id = 2)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM Provider P2 
              WHERE C.company_id = P2.company_id 
              AND P2.service_id = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer this option for the subquery...

```
SELECT b.company_id 
  FROM provider b WHERE b.service_id = 2
INTERSECT
SELECT b.company_id 
  FROM provider b WHERE b.service_id = 4
```

Often, I find the performance of these operations to be outstanding even with very large data sets...

- UNION
- INTERSECT
- EXCEPT (or MINUS in Oracle)

This article has some good insights:

[You Probably Don't Use SQL Intersect or Except Often Enough](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/10/06/you-probably-dont-use-sql-intersect-or-except-often-enough/)

Hope it helps.